# Convert to lower and upper bits

Tags: c#, byte

I have a device and I have some values  that user sets in GUI, that will be like `630` `330` etc. I need these values passed to I2C bytes. 583will be `02 47` in hex bits. that will be in 2 byte variables and I need to call `Set(byte lower ,byte upper)` so to convert an int or double value to 2 bytes is the requirement.

I tried :

```
            ushort R1x = (ushort)Rx;
            byte upper = (byte)(R1x >> 8);
            byte lower = (byte)(R1x & 0xff);
```

What I needed is lower = 47 and upper = 02.

Which is giving `lower = 0` and `upper = 247` ..May I know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Tried it for `ushort Rx = 245 * 256 + 130;` and works fine. Maybe give additional code?

Comment: I didn't got what you said . And I miss the logic actually.

Comment: Your way of grabbing upper and lower 8-bits from 16-bit value is correct, but still you're getting the wrong `lower` and `upper`, IMO there's something unexpected about `R1x` value.

Comment: @Zigma Can you show us the code that sets `Rx`?

Comment: @blt currently I am just assigning it.

Comment: What is the value of R1x after the first line?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419453/getting-upper-and-lower-byte-of-an-integer-in-c-sharp-and-putting-it-as-a-char-a

Comment: You can just remove the `& 0xFF`. Casting to bytes only keeps the last 8 bits because a byte only has 8 bits...

Comment: @usr Yes I seen and that is what I am tried. but am I doing write thing?

Comment: "What I needed is lower = 47 and upper = 02." - I doubt it. That would mean a decimal split, that's extremely unusual especially in low level protocols.

Comment: @Zigma Seeing the code that assigns `Rx` would clarify things much more quickly than your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can give you `lower = 0` and `upper = 247` for `Rx = 247`, because [`ushort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbf1574z.aspx) is a 16bit value, and `247` fits on 8 bits. That's why upper 8 bits are zero (not needed to hold 247) and lower bits are holding the whole number, which is 247 or `00000000 11110111` in binary.

The first number which will give you non-zero upper bits is 256 (`00000001 00000000`), for which:

```
upper = 1
lower = 0
```

To have `upper = 47` you need to reverse the process, so let's write it as a 8 bit binary number: `00101111`. Then put those 8 bits as upper bits of a 16 bit number: `00101111 00000000`. Since you want `lower = 2` we need to put 2 in in the right 8 bits. This gives `00101111 00000010` binary which is equal to 12034 decimal.

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but for the code you've provided `Rx = 12034` is the only possibility to have upper and lower equal to what you desire. So if that doesn't suit your protocol, then you've made a mistake somewhere else.