# Getting High/ Low Byte from ushort results in incorrect result

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

So I'm currently writing a Library that will help me interface with a Fingerprint Scanner over a USB-Port [this](https://www.brack.ch/velleman-sensor-zfm-708-fingerabdruck-871758) one in fact, which is just a resold Zhiantec (documentation [here](https://www.velleman.eu/downloads/29/infosheets/vma329_datasheet.pdf)).

So the problem I'm running in to is this: The documentation specifies that the Header bytes, the Header, Package Length and Checksum bytes are to be transferred high byte first. Not a big deal, after a quick google I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5419500/9363973) answer by Jon Skeet showing exactly how to do this. I then put this into two small helper methods that look like this:

```cs
public static class ByteHelper
{
    // Low/ High byte arithmetic
    // byte upper = (byte) (number >> 8);
    // byte lower = (byte) (number & 0xff);

    public static byte[] GetBytesOrderedLowHigh(ushort toBytes)
    {
        return new[] {(byte) (toBytes & 0xFF), (byte) (toBytes >> 8)};
    }

    public static byte[] GetBytesOrderedHighLow(ushort toBytes)
    {
        return new[] {(byte) (toBytes >> 8), (byte) (toBytes & 0xFF)};
    }
}
```

Which I'm testing to see if they do the correct thing with this code:

```cs
// Expected Output '0A-00', actual '00-0A'
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(ByteHelper.GetBytesOrderedHighLow(10)));

// Expected Output '00-0A', actual '0A-00'
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(ByteHelper.GetBytesOrderedLowHigh(10)));
```

But I'm getting the wrong output (see comments above Console.WriteLine statements), can anyone explain me why it's doing this and how to fix it?

Comment: _"why it's doing this"_ - read about endianness. You might just want to reverse the array.

Comment: Are you sure you are not confused method names?

Comment: @Vasek I did not confuse the method names (you can check yourself in the Test code)

Comment: I checked. And everything works as it should be.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for the tip, will definitely read about it

Comment: @Vasek the problem seems to be with the Endianness of the system, I'm running this on a Little Endian system, th BitConverter Class has a property to see this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results you get are correct.

Your `LowHigh`-Method switches the two bytes.

> 00-0A will be 0A-00

Your `HighLow`-Method does only convert the `ushort` into an byte-array.

> 00-0A will stay 00-0A

Here a step-by-step-example of your logic, with some more outputs for better understanding:

```
ulong x = 0x0A0B0C;
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("X6"));
// We're only interested in last 2 Bytes:
ulong x2 = x & 0xFFFF;

// Now let's get those last 2 bytes:
byte upperByte = (byte)(x2 >> 8); // Shift 8 bytes -> tell get dropped
Console.WriteLine(upperByte.ToString("X2"));
byte lowerByte = (byte)(x2 & 0xFF); // Only last Byte is left
Console.WriteLine(lowerByte.ToString("X2"));

// The question is: What do you want to do with it? Switch or leave it in this order?

// leave them in the current order:
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(new byte[] { upperByte, lowerByte }));

// switch positions:
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(new byte[] { lowerByte, upperByte }));
```

Comment: You're totally right. I misunderstood the definitions of High/ Low byte